# How to display on the same JSP a resource bundle key several time but in different locales?

Tags: struts2, internationalization, jstl, locale

Dear Struts 2 and JSP experts,

I can't figure out how to display on the same page a resource bundle key several time but with different locales.

Resource Bundles:

*global_fr.properties*

```
#Global messages
global.label = Texte en Français
```

*global.properties*

```
#Global messages
global.label = Text in English
```

Expected result:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Texte en Français</td>
    <td>${param.label.fr}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text in English</td>
    <td>${param.label.en}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What is the best way to handle this use case with Struts 2 or JSTL ?

Thanks for your help,

Bertrand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use S2 `<s:i18n>` tag for that which allows the `<s:text>` tag *to access messages from any bundle, and not just the bundle associated with the current action*.

```
<s:i18n name="global_fr">
    <s:text name="global.label"/>
</s:i18n>

<s:i18n name="global_en">
    <s:text name="global.label"/>
</s:i18n>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply ! I didn't know I could use <s:i18n> tag to force the name of the bundle; bundle of a specific locale in my case.